# Integrating Discrete point in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have two numpy array (x,y)-

```
import numpy as np
import scipy 
from scipy.integrate import simps

y=np.array([1,1,2,1,-2])
x=np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
```

Which when plotted look like this - (in Blue line)
[image]
The black lines highlight the actual points. I wish to integrate between two points (marked red line) on x axis which are not in the original dataset. The goal is to find the area shaded in gray (between the two red lines) in the figure above.

How do I do it in python? Using python SciPy library I can integrate like this

```
scipy.integrate.trapz(y,x)
```

That gives me the area shaded in the gray region- [image]

But if I integrate between the points say 1.5 and 2.2 on x axis, the trapz gives the area shaded in gray below- [image]

How do I get this correct.

PS- The line graph cannot be expressed as a function as there are many random points in the original array.

Any insight in the right direction would be helpful

Comment: `The line graph cannot be expressed as a function as there are many random points in the original array` - How is that a problem? You can just  interpolate the values between two points.

Comment: ok fine. But how do I integrate. Which function to use?

Comment: Use `numpy.interp` to get your new data points between which you want to integrate. Here's the official documentation: [link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scipy interpolators (such as [`InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html)) have an `integral` method.  For example,

```
In [23]: from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

In [24]: x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [25]: y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 1, -2])

In [26]: f = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(x, y, k=1)  # k=1 gives linear interpolation

In [27]: f.integral(1.5, 2.2)
Out[27]: 1.2550000000000003
```

Comment: Note on `integral`: 'A caveat is that this routine assumes the spline to be zero outside of the data limits', [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.integral.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.integral)