# How to calculate the area of the positive part of a graph in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe

```
>>print(df)
                          Power
timestamp                      
2019-02-16 00:00:00  -7240.2360
2019-02-16 01:00:00  -7598.0856
2019-02-16 02:00:00  -7563.9708
2019-02-16 03:00:00  -7247.5380
2019-02-16 04:00:00  -7167.5292
2019-02-16 05:00:00  -7540.6572
2019-02-16 06:00:00  -8856.7836
2019-02-16 07:00:00  -5313.8868
2019-02-16 08:00:00   1019.7360
2019-02-16 09:00:00    853.9788
2019-02-16 10:00:00  24312.1020
2019-02-16 11:00:00  45792.9588
2019-02-16 12:00:00  48332.9124
2019-02-16 13:00:00  40819.7460
2019-02-16 14:00:00  46905.9012
2019-02-16 15:00:00  33089.8188
2019-02-16 16:00:00  38144.0256
2019-02-16 17:00:00  20626.7040
2019-02-16 18:00:00   4575.4176
2019-02-16 19:00:00  -5906.9352
2019-02-16 20:00:00  -8736.6144
2019-02-16 21:00:00  -8649.7056
2019-02-16 22:00:00  -7612.5216
2019-02-16 23:00:00  -7432.0824
```

If I plot them I have:

```
df.plot()
```

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLM32.png)

The problem is I don't know how to calculate the area between the curve and x-axis in the positive part. I'm thinking about getting the x coordinates when the curve crosses with x-axis, which is [ 8.83899641 19.43648766], but I don't know what next should I do.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964727/integrating-discrete-point-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can first filter df by positive values. Then use `np.trapz`:

```
#Preparing data
import numpy as np
string = """Power     timestamp
2019-02-16 00:00:00     -7240.2360
2019-02-16 01:00:00     -7598.0856
2019-02-16 02:00:00     -7563.9708
2019-02-16 03:00:00     -7247.5380
2019-02-16 04:00:00     -7167.5292
2019-02-16 05:00:00     -7540.6572
2019-02-16 06:00:00     -8856.7836
2019-02-16 07:00:00     -5313.8868
2019-02-16 08:00:00      1019.7360
2019-02-16 09:00:00      853.9788
2019-02-16 10:00:00     24312.1020
2019-02-16 11:00:00     45792.9588
2019-02-16 12:00:00     48332.9124
2019-02-16 13:00:00     40819.7460
2019-02-16 14:00:00     46905.9012
2019-02-16 15:00:00     33089.8188
2019-02-16 16:00:00     38144.0256
2019-02-16 17:00:00     20626.7040
2019-02-16 18:00:00      4575.4176
2019-02-16 19:00:00     -5906.9352
2019-02-16 20:00:00     -8736.6144
2019-02-16 21:00:00     -8649.7056
2019-02-16 22:00:00     -7612.5216
2019-02-16 23:00:00     -7432.0824"""
data = [x.split('     ') for x in string.split('\n')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns = data[0])
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].astype(float)

#Filtering negatives
posdf = df[df['timestamp']>0]
posdf.plot()
#Solution
np.trapz(posdf['timestamp'])
```

Output:

[image]

Based on the comment:

```
s = [0,5,-1,0,0,-1,5,0]
s = [x for x in s if x>=0]
plt.plot(s)
np.trapz(s)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This seems dangerous if two non-contiguous positive sections exist.  You'll end up with an extraneous area with a height of the average of the last and first positive values and a length of the negative section.

Comment: @Daniel F Look at the answer.

Comment: I mean, yeah, if you engineer the data to include 0 that won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Get area of Positive part of array graph
print(np.trapz(df[df>0],x=df[df>0]))
#Get area of negative part of array graph
print(np.trapz(df[df<0],x=df[df<0]))
```